# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, httpclient

I am trying to write a simple WebService Testing using HTTPClient. I have all my jars loaded up but get the above error message.

Why am I getting this error message?

Here is the code:

```
package HTTPClientTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.junit.Assert;


public class RESTTester {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

    String restURL_XML = "http://parabank.parasoft.com/parabank/services/bank/customers/12212/";


    try {

    testStatusCode(restURL_XML);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}


public static void testStatusCode(String restURL) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(restURL);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);
    Assert.assertEquals(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(),HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    }

}
```

Below is the error stacktrace,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:966)
    at HTTPClientTest.RESTTester.testStatusCode(RESTTester.java:37)
    at HTTPClientTest.RESTTester.main(RESTTester.java:22)
```

Comment: Could you share your stack trace with me? I can't do **anything** without that.

Comment: @Chuchoo please edit the stacktrace into the question..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got above error because I had multiple older versions of HTTPClient in my project. I removed older versions of HTTPClient and now the error message is gone.

Comment: I had the same reason.

Comment: which version should I use?

Comment: i had same issue. removing older version jars from classpath fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

By analysing your stack trace, I found out your program is written good. It seems that apache HTTP APIs were compiled wrong. Maybe the package `org.apache.http.impl.client`was compiled against different version of `org.apache.http.conn.ssl` than you are using? Upgrade both packages to their newest versions and retry. Report it to HTTPClient bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I found a jar named `apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar` beside `httpclient-4.4.1.jar` and `httpcore-4.4.1.jar`.

I just remove the `apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar` and worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I`ve come across this error(java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE) several times. With different reasons here it is INSTANCE. 
This error is conveying about the mismatch between the aws-java-sdk-core library and one of the service-specific SDK`s aws-sdk-s3 or aws-java-sdk-sqs.

I faced this error while using aws-java-sdk-core(1.11.289) with aws-sdk-s3(1.11.428). Fixed it by using the following aws-java-sdk-core(1.11.289) with aws-sdk-s3(1.11.186).