# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE in AWS SNS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sms

I am trying to send sms via Amazon Web service . I have downloaded the sd
    package com.sms;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sms.AwsClientFactoryDemo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.MessageAttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishResult;

public class SmsNotificationService {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SmsNotificationService.class);

    public PublishResult send(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
        smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withStringValue("Lightside") //The sender ID shown on the device (except in US)
                .withDataType("String"));
        smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withStringValue("0.01") //Sets the max price to 0.01 USD.
                .withDataType("Number"));
        smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withStringValue("Promotional") //Sets the type to promotional.
                .withDataType("String"));
        PublishResult result = AwsClientFactoryDemo.getSnsClient().publish(new PublishRequest()
                .withMessage(message)
                .withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
        LOG.info("Sent SMS message ID: " + result.getMessageId());
        return result;
    }

}
```

I am getting following error in the above code while trying to send sms via aws sns.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:87)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:39)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:300)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:164)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:153)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.<init>(AmazonSNSClient.java:207)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.<init>(AmazonSNSClient.java:187)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.<init>(AmazonSNSClient.java:97)
    at com.sms.sms.main(sms.java:13)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely caused by different versions of the HTTP client dependency on the classpath. ([Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38166380/1428388), [Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21628650/1428388)) Make sure you only have one version on the classpath.

Comment: i have included following jar files :

Comment: aws-java-sdk-1.11.41.jar aws-java-sdk-1.11.41-javadoc.jar , aws-java-sdk-1.11.41-sources.jar , jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar , commons-logging-1.1.2.jar , slf4j.jar, com.fasterxml.jacksoncore.jar ,

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar , com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar , apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar , apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar , httpclient-4.4.jar , httpcore-4.3.jar

Comment: Thanks , i removed the older versions . It's working now